# Visualforce JQuery get value of pageBlockTable cell

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

I have a VF page with a pageblockTable which has buttons at the end I need to enable/disable based on the value of a cell in the table row. The last row in the table has text in it, but my script does not seem to pick it up.

What am I doing wrong? The Edit button in row 7 should be enabled because the memo cell has a value, but the alert returns no value. What do I need to change in the script code?

[image]

```
    j$(document).ready(function() {

    var empty = false;
    var mem = '';
    j$('.memo').each(function() {
        alert('in loop');
        mem = j$(this).val();
        if (mem == '') {
            alert(mem);
            j$('[id*=edit]').attr('disabled', 'true');
        } else {
            j$('[id*=edit]').removeAttr('disabled');
        }

        });
});


<apex:pageblockTable styleClass="cc_row" width="95%" rowClasses="odd,even" value="{!CCActivities}" var="cca">
<apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" 
                        changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
<apex:column styleclass="cc_col8" headerValue="Call Cycle Activity Name">
    <apex:outputLink styleClass="lineId" id="ccaId" value="{!URLFOR($Action.CallCycleActivity__c.View, cca.Id)}" target="_blank">{!cca.Name}</apex:outputLink>
</apex:column>
<apex:column styleclass="cc_col3" headerValue="Main Contact" value="{!cca.Main_Contact__c}"/>
<apex:column styleclass="cc_col8" headerValue="Account Name">
    <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Account.View, cca.Account__r.Id)}" target="_blank">{!cca.Account__r.Name}</apex:outputLink>
</apex:column>
<apex:column styleclass="memo" headerValue="Instruction Memo" value="{!cca.Main_Contact__r.LastMemoContent__c}"/>
<apex:column styleclass="cc_col3" headerValue="Add/Edit Memo">
    <apex:commandButton value="Add"                                     action="/a08/e?RecordType=012O00000008w52&CF00NO0000001OYtC={!cca.Main_Contact__r.Name}&CF00NO0000001OYtC_lkid={!cca.Main_Contact__r.Id}&00NO0000001O4at=Information&saveURL=/apex/CallCycleListView?id={!cca.CallCycle__c}&retURL=/apex/CallCycleListView?id={!cca.CallCycle__c}&CF00NO0000001ZgWh={!cca.Name}&00NO0000001OYtH=CC%20Instruction" />-->
    <apex:commandButton value="Edit" disabled="true" id="edit"                                                      action="/a08/e?id={!cca.Main_Contact__r.Last_Memo__c}&saveURL=/apex/CallCycleListView?Id={!cca.CallCycle__c}&retURL=/apex/CallCycleListView?id={!cca.CallCycle__c}" />
</apex:column>
```

Comment: try `.text()` instead of `.val()`. It is not an input it should be a div or td

Comment: Thanks Eric, that worked to pick up the content! Now the enabling of the Edit button is still not working though (sorry my javascript is not the best!) - could you help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .text() instead of .val(). It is not an input it should be a div or td

For the edit button use the "ends with" selector and disabled should be disabled for a value not true:

```
j$('[id$=edit]').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

or try

```
j$('[id$=edit]').prop("disabled",true);
```

**Example Using Account that works**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" cache="false">

    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"/>


<script>

    $(document).ready( function(){
        $('[id$=testbtn]').prop('disabled',true);
    });

</script>

<apex:form >

    <apex:commandButton id="testbtn" onclick="alert('opps'); return false;" value="Try Me" rerender=""/>


</apex:form>



</apex:page>
```

Comment: I tried both, but neither work... I also tried what Scott suggested but no luck with that either.

Comment: @Irene - Are you getting your alert? Maybe your comparison to '' is wrong

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the alert

Comment: @Irene - See my example above where the button is disabled. NOTE: The style does not look disabled, you have to apply that using css, but the button does not work. If you comment out the script stuff you will see the button works. Take that and adapt it to your scenario.....

Comment: I created your page and that works yes, but maybe mine doesn't because it has multiple instances of the button, as it's in a table. Funny thing is that even though the buttons are all disabled, when I click on any of them, it refreshes the page! Why would that happen? My script is now:         j$('.memo').each(function() {
            mem = j$(this).text();
            if (mem == '') {
          j$('[id$=edit]').prop('disabled',true);
         } else {
                alert('true');
          j$('[id$=edit]').prop('disabled',false);
         }

Comment: @Irene - it refreshes your page because you do not have a rerender attribute on the button so standard behavior is to refresh the page. add rerender="". Please accept an answer and continue new questions in a separate question on SFSE to keep the info searchable

Comment: Thanks - I got it working, but the answer is a combination of your and @Scott's answer! Do I post a new answer - that won't credit either of you though, so how do I do it?

Comment: @Irene - not getting it the middle of that one. Just make sure you up vote the other....It really is your call. Pick the answer that you feel would be most helpful to others having a similar issue.....Thats all that matters here is that someone can get a resolution to a similar problem

Answer (score 4):

Just posting the full solution here, thanks to both @Eric and @Scott:

```
        (function() {
        var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

        j$(document).ready(function() {
            j$('.memo').each(function() {
                var hasValue = (j$(this).text());
                alert(hasValue);
                if(!j$(this).text()){
                    j$(this).closest('tr').find('td[id$="add_edit"] input[id$="edit"]').prop('disabled', true);
                } else {
                    j$(this).closest('tr').find('td[id$="add_edit"] input[id$="edit"]').removeProp('disabled');
                }
            });
        });

    })()
```

And the VF column looks like this (no disabled setting):

```
    <apex:column styleclass="add_edit" headerValue="Add/Edit Memo">
  <apex:commandButton value="Add" action="/a08/e?RecordType=012O00000008w52&CF00NO0000001OYtC={!cca.Main_Contact__r.Name}&CF00NO0000001OYtC_lkid={!cca.Main_Contact__r.Id}&00NO0000001O4at=Information&saveURL=/apex/CallCycleListView?id={!cca.CallCycle__c}&retURL=/apex/CallCycleListView?id={!cca.CallCycle__c}&CF00NO0000001ZgWh={!cca.Name}&00NO0000001OYtH=CC%20Instruction" />
  <apex:commandButton value="Edit" id="edit" action="/a08/e?id={!cca.Main_Contact__r.Last_Memo__c}&saveURL=/apex/CallCycleListView?Id={!cca.CallCycle__c}&retURL=/apex/CallCycleListView?id={!cca.CallCycle__c}" />
</apex:column>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of things going on.

1. You have `<apex:column styleclass="memo" ...`, so use `j$('[id$="memo"]')` instead of `j$('.memo')` to query the `apex:columns`.
2. As @Eric said, use `.text()` instead of `.val()` as @Eric said since the `apex:columns` are `td`s and not `input`s.
3. If you're using jQuery 1.6+, use `.prop(...)` instead of `.attr(...)`.
4. When you're trying to toggle the disabled attribute of the Edit `commandButtons`, you need to find the `commandButtons`:  you start at the `memo` column, so you need to go to the closest `tr`, then find the `cc_col3` `td`, then find the `edit` input.

Code:

```
j$(document).ready(function() {
    j$('td[id$="memo"]').each(function() {
        alert('in loop');
        if(!j$(this).text()){
            j$(this).closest('tr').find('td[id$="cc_col3"] input[id$="edit"]').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            j$(this).closest('tr').find('td[id$="cc_col3"] input[id$="edit"]').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

or even simpler:

```
j$(document).ready(function() {
    j$('td[id$="memo"]').each(function() {
        var hasValue = (j$(this).text());
        j$(this).closest('tr').find('td[id$="cc_col3"] input[id$="edit"]').prop('disabled', !hasValue);
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried that but it won't change the attribute for the button. I renamed the td style as there are others with the same style:
<apex:column styleclass="add_edit" headerValue="Add/Edit Memo">
It still won't enable the Edit button.

Comment: I also added an id to the column:
<apex:column styleclass="add_edit" id="add_edit" headerValue="Add/Edit Memo">
 and tried with both the 'disabled' and the 'rendered' attribute, but that doesn't work either.
<apex:commandButton value="Edit" disabled="true" id="edit" ...
<apex:commandButton value="Edit" rendered="false" id="edit" ...